# javascript count number

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c=0;
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount()
{
document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
c=c+1;
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",30);
}

function doTimer()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
  {
  timer_is_on=1;
  timedCount();
  }
}
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Start count!" onClick="doTimer()">
<input type="text" id="txt">
</form>
<p>Click on the button above. The input field will count forever, starting at 0.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I modify this code to let it stop at 100?
Thanks!

Comment: just a note, it's better to use a function object rather than a code in string: `setTimeout(timedCount, 30)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (c >= 100){ 
   //do stuff
}else{
    t=setTimeout("timedCount()",30);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",30);
```

with

```
if(c < 100) { 
    t=setTimeout("timedCount()",30);
}
```

Try to do it yourself next time, this one was really easy...

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

just add this line at top of function TimedCount

```
function TimedCount ()
{
    if (c>100) return;

    // use your existing code below

}
```